# Scaling a 'factory' design approach when listing contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, factory

I am building a smart contract that uses a factory contract to deploy a new sub-contract (example some campaign). This campaign has a boolean flag `isActive`. Every time the factory deploys a campaign, it inserts its address to an array so I can have a method like `getCampaigns()` which returns an array of all campaign addresses.

My questions are:

1. If the system ends up with hundreds of thousands of campaigns, how
   can `getCampaigns()` remain efficient? Is there something like
   pagination design patterns?
2. An idea I have is to make a function that displays only active Campaigns. But at the factory level, the contract does not have access to the variables inside the respective Campaign. Is it possible to design something like that?

For posterity, this is the code I am using:

```
contract CampaignFactory {
    Campaign[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(string memory campaignName) public payable {
        Campaign newCampaign = (new Campaign).value(msg.value)(msg.sender, campaignName);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    }

    function getCampaigns() public view returns (Campaign[] memory) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }

    // Is it possible to get only active campaigns using the campaignActive boolean?
    function getActiveCampaigns() public view returns (Campaign[] memory) {
        //
    }
}

contract Campaign {
    address public campaignManager; 
    string public campaignName;
    bool public campaignActive; 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to your 1st question**

You can do something like this

```
function getCampaigns(int start, int end) public returns(Campaign[] memory) {
        for(int i = start ; i < end && end <= deployedCampaigns.length; i++) {
            Campaign.push(deployedCampaigns[i])
        }
        return
    }
```

**Solution to your 2nd question**

You can get the value of `campaignActive` on `Campaign` contract.

Just add a new getter function in `Campaign` contract

```
function getCampaignActive() public view returns(bool) {
   return campaignActive;
}
```

And then you can access use the `campaignActive` check to check if the campaign is active or not and push only those with `campaignActive = true`

```
 function getActiveCampaigns() public view returns (Campaigns[] memory) {
      for(uint i = 0; i < deployedCampaigns.length; i ++){
         if(Campaign(deployedCampaigns[i]).getCampaignActive()) {
            Campaigns.push(deployedCampaigns[i])
         }
      }
      return
 }
```

**Note** Code is not tested